# Converting a summed sql query to LINQ

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I have the following SQL code from a legacy application that I have been given to work on:

```
SELECT  [timePeriodLabel]
            ,[tariffCost]
            ,[totalUnits]
            ,[totalMoneyValue]
    into    #allRates
    FROM    [halfHourlyCustomers3NF].[dbo].[halfHourlyBillsTariffTotals]
    where   invoiceNumber = @invoiceNumber

    select  'eveningAndWeekend' as timePeriodLabel,
            tariffcost,
            sum(totalUnits) as totalUnits,
            sum(totalMoneyValue) as totalMoneyValue
    into    #newCollection
    from    #allRates
    where   timePeriodLabel = 'evening' or
            timePeriodLabel = 'weekend'
    group by tariffcost

    insert into #newCollection 
    select  'winterDay' as timePeriodLabel,
            tariffcost,
            sum(totalUnits) as totalUnits,
            sum(totalMoneyValue) as totalMoneyValue
    from    #allRates
    where   timePeriodLabel = 'winterDayBeforePeak' or
            timePeriodLabel = 'winterDayAfterPeak'
    group by tariffcost

    insert into #newCollection 
    select  'night' as timePeriodLabel,
            tariffcost as tariffCost,
            sum(totalUnits) as totalUnits,
            sum(totalMoneyValue) as totalMoneyValue
    from    #allRates
    where   timePeriodLabel = 'nightWeekday' or
            timePeriodLabel = 'morningWeekday' or
            timePeriodLabel = 'nightWeekend' or
            timePeriodLabel = 'morningWeekend'
    group by tariffcost

    insert into #newCollection 
    select  * 
    from    #allRates 
    where   not(timePeriodLabel  = 'winterDayBeforePeak' or
            timePeriodLabel = 'winterDayAfterPeak' or
            timePeriodLabel = 'nightWeekday' or
            timePeriodLabel = 'morningWeekday' or
            timePeriodLabel = 'nightWeekend' or
            timePeriodLabel = 'morningWeekend'or
            timePeriodLabel = 'evening' or
            timePeriodLabel = 'weekend')

    select  * 
    from    #newCollection
```

This helps to filter and sum data from a table as follows:

```
winterDayBeforePeak 12.0000 926.5850    111.1900
winterDayAfterPeak  12.0000 151.7650    18.2100
winterPeak          13.0000 331.5100    43.1000
evening              6.0000 172.9250    10.3800
weekend              6.0000 616.5350    36.9900
nightWeekday         8.0000 1362.5150   109.0000
morningWeekday       8.0000 3627.2750   290.1800
nightWeekend         8.0000 533.8800    42.7100
morningWeekend       8.0000 1439.3100   115.1400
```

I have created an Entity framework application with a List variable called `TariffTotals` and I want to add the results of the query transformation into another List variable called `SummerTariffTotals`

I have looked on MDSN for the documentation to do this and I came across this article:[EF Summing Link][1]

Having looked at some answers on Stack Overflow I have tried the following:

```
var test = db.TariffCaclulations.GroupBy(row => new { row.TariffCost })
                .Select(g => new HalfHourlyBillTariffCalculation()
                {
                    TimePeriodLabel = "eveningAndWeekend",
                    TariffCost = g.Key.TariffCost,
                    TotalUnits = g.Sum(x => x.TotalUnits),
                    TotalMoneyValue = g.Sum(x => x.TotalMoneyValue)
                })
                .ToList();
```

Once I have the variable I was then going to add it to the summed table but I am getting an error **The entity or complex type 'Project.Models.HalfHourlyBillTariffCalculation' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."}**

Any pointers on how I can overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that you can't create complex type. That means you can't create new Entity object from your linq query. You should create POCO object and everything should be fine:

Your POCO class:

```
public class HalfHourlyBillTariffCalculationPOCO
{
   public string TimePeriodLabel { get; set; }
   public decimal TariffCost { get; set; }
   public decimal TotalUnits { get; set; }
   public decimal TotalMoneyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then your cal use it easily:

```
var test = db.TariffCaclulations.GroupBy(row => new { row.TariffCost })
                .Select(g => new HalfHourlyBillTariffCalculationPOCO()
                {
                    TimePeriodLabel = "eveningAndWeekend",
                    TariffCost = g.Key.TariffCost,
                    TotalUnits = g.Sum(x => x.TotalUnits),
                    TotalMoneyValue = g.Sum(x => x.TotalMoneyValue)
                })
                .ToList();
```